# What triggers the change function in back

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

Sort of a novice javascript person reading a backbone.js tutorial http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/docs/5.html and have a few questions about some of the code the author uses.

In the initialize function below, the author binds

```
  this.model.bind('change', this.render);
  this.model.bind('remove', this.unrender);
```

I'm assuming this means the `render` function is called on the 'this' object whenever the change function is called, and `unrender`is run whenever `remove` is called. The problem, for me, is that there is a defined function `'remove'` in his code, but no defined function `'change'`

Question: Do `change` and `remove` refer to jquery functions or does the `remove` function refer to the `remove` function defined in the code (i.e. it overrides the jquery function) while `change` refers to the jquery function. If the latter, what exactly triggers the `'change'` function if it's never explicitly called and, hence, the `render` function?

Code

```
var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li', // name of tag to be created        


    events: { 
      'click span.swap':  'swap',
      'click span.delete': 'remove'
    },    


    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'unrender', 'swap', 'remove'); // every function that uses 'this' as the current object should be in here

      this.model.bind('change', this.render);
      this.model.bind('remove', this.unrender);
    },


    render: function(){
      $(this.el).html('<span style="color:black;">'+this.model.get('part1')+' '+this.model.get('part2')+'</span> &nbsp; &nbsp; <span class="swap" style="font-family:sans-serif; color:blue; cursor:pointer;">[swap]</span> <span class="delete" style="cursor:pointer; color:red; font-family:sans-serif;">[delete]</span>');
      return this; // for chainable calls, like .render().el
    },


    unrender: function(){
      $(this.el).remove();
    },


    swap: function(){
      var swapped = {
        part1: this.model.get('part2'), 
        part2: this.model.get('part1')
      };
      this.model.set(swapped);
    },



    remove: function(){
      this.model.destroy();
    }
  });
```

​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `change` and `remove` are Backbone events, not jQuery events. These:

```
this.model.bind('change', this.render);
this.model.bind('remove', this.unrender);
```

mean that `this.render` will be called when the model triggers a `change` event and `this.unrender` will be called when the model triggers a `remove` event. The [`set` method on models](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-set):

> **set** `model.set(attributes, [options])`
>
> Set a hash of attributes (one or many) on the model. If any of the attributes change the models state, a `"change"` event will be triggered, unless `{silent: true}` is passed as an option.

is one way to trigger a model's `change` event, [`unset`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-unset) and [`clear`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-clear) will also trigger `change` events.

`remove` events generally come from collections but the collection will send them through the appropriate models in case there are views listening.

You might want to read the (quite good) [Backbone documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) and review the [Catalog of Events](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-events) in particular.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand the change event now but what triggers remove in this code? is it the explicit call to 'remove' and if that doesn't exist how would remove be triggered?

Comment: @Michael: I don't see anything in there that would trigger a `remove` event, that usually comes from [`Collection#remove`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-remove). The `remove` method on the view would trigger a [`destroy`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-destroy) event.

Comment: so this line is insignificant? this.model.bind('remove', this.unrender);  I thought remove needed to be triggered for unrender to then get triggered.

Comment: There is a collection in `ListView`, and calling [`Model#destroy`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-destroy) and that bubbles an event up to the collection which (I think) triggers a `remove` event on the collection which triggers a `remove` on the model.